# Can I get hard returns in the text of a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a situation where I have three columns in a DataGridView which are simple DataGridViewTextBoxColumns.  In a row, first column has a label, the next two columns have multiline data, and if I set the WrapMode to true, it will show the hard returns as multiple lines.  All three columns are read-only.

The problem is that the lines in the second column correspond to the lines in the third column, kind of like mini-rows within the row.  If the text on one line exceeds the width, that is wrapped to the next line and the alignment between the columns is off.

If I turn WrapMode to false, the hard returns are not shown.

Can I get it to wrap the text based on the hard returns, but not on the length of each line?  I would hope not to have to refactor it to use multiple rows because each row currently is a single object.

Could I do it with a custom column type?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably refactor it, since the whole point of DataGridView is to show a database-style table of results.

However, if you're set on not doing that, you could do it by manually painting the cell.